# Cumulative Constraint OR-Tools

Tags: constraint-programming, or-tools, c++

I'm trying to solve an rcpsp model.

I can't find documentation for the `AddCumulative` function of OR-Tools. How should this function be used?

I want to write this constraint in C++:
$$\forall k \in R,\quad\text{cumulative}(s, p_{j}, [r_{jk}\mid j\in J\mid R_{k}])$$ ($s$ is my decision variable, a vector that saves the period of when the job begins, $p_{j}$ is the duration of activity $j$, $r_{jk}$ is the amount of resource used by activity $j$ and $R_{k}$ is the capacity of the resource $k$ each day), but the OR-Tools module apparently takes only one argument, although I've seen some examples where it takes 3.

Actually, if I give the function the parameter RHS, which is the resource capacity (what it is asking for), I get this error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘operations_research::sat::CpModelBuilder::AddCumulative(int*&)’
     cp_model.AddCumulative(rhs);
                               ^
```

In addition, the command prompt says that RHS must be `IntVar` but is `int`.
So, my question is, what is the capacity that the function must take? And what happens with the other values like `IntervalVar` and resource consumption by job?

Comment: What is the $p$? What is $R_k$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at [OR-Tools: CumulativeConstraint](http://google.github.io/or-tools/cpp_sat/classoperations__research_1_1sat_1_1CpModelBuilder.html#a7eaa53689ca6adc2a83db42dfb81e2ed), `AddCumulative` takes a variable as argument, so if it is constant, create a variable with a fixed domain.

It returns a `CumulativeConstraint` with a method to add (`IntervalVar`, `DemandVar`) pairs to the constraint. See [OR-Tools 7.4: C++ Reference (CumulativeConstraint)](http://google.github.io/or-tools/cpp_sat/classoperations__research_1_1sat_1_1CumulativeConstraint.html).

Note that the rcpcp solver is implemented in python [here](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/rcpsp_sat.py)

Here is a C++ code snippet with the cumulative constraint:

```
  const IntervalVar x = cp_model.NewIntervalVar(cp_model.NewIntVar({0, 20}),
                                                cp_model.NewConstant(5),
                                                cp_model.NewIntVar({0, 20}));
  const IntervalVar y = cp_model.NewIntervalVar(cp_model.NewIntVar({0, 20}),
                                                cp_model.NewConstant(5),
                                                cp_model.NewIntVar({0, 20}));
  const IntVar a = cp_model.NewIntVar({5, 10});
  const IntVar b = cp_model.NewIntVar({5, 10});
  const IntVar c = cp_model.NewIntVar({5, 10});

  CumulativeConstraint cumul = cp_model.AddCumulative(a);
  cumul.AddDemand(x, b);
  cumul.AddDemand(y, c);
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Thanks Laurent. The example is in python and the cumulative uses 3 arguments. is there another example in c++ using cumulative function? Im trying to create an object cumulative and using the method add for each job but i don't know how to declare it.

Comment: edited my answer to add a code snippet.

Comment: thanks, it works!

Comment: Hi Laurent, what should i do if i have multiple resources, its possible to create a vector of CumulativeConstraint objects (i tried). If i just declare them apparently the new object overwrites the previous one. Is there a way?

Comment: just add the relevant intervals to all cumulative constraints.